# Netbeans 8.2 crashes at startup with macOs Monterey 12.0.1

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8.2

Netbeans 8.2, which has been good in previous macOs versions, crashes at startup. Monterey 12.0.1 installed.
I can start java manually from the path that is mentioned in the text.

### Message:
Translated Report (Full Report Below)

Process:               java [16597]
Path:                  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
Identifier:            java
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [16335]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-10-26 18:26:48.7780 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        907EBB96-115C-4D1D-1DF7-BCBF08A61DEA

Time Awake Since Boot: 11000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        49  Java: Thread-6

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0:: AppKit Thread Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808ca3aba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808ca3e2b mach_msg + 59
2   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff808da7a42 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 319
3   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff808da611b __CFRunLoopRun + 1325

Comment: https://netbeans.apache.org/ `Latest release
Apache NetBeans 12.5`

Comment: consider posting this on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crash

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crash

Comment: [1] That `"Identifier: java Version: ???"` looks ominous! Is it possible that you have multiple versions of Java installed, and you are not picking up 8u141? My guess (and nothing more) is that you are starting NetBeans 8.2 using a version of Java > 8. That would be invalid and unsupported. [2] Regardless of that, Update 141 is old. You should be using the latest update for JDK 8 to avoid potential security issues. [3] Also, as c69 implied, 8.2 is now a very old release of NetBeans, and is unsupported AFAIK. Are you required to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. I agree that 8.2 is an old and out of scope.
I upgraded to Netbeans 12.5, edit the config file for Netbeans to use an updated JDK version8. Works perfectly. Old projects were imported and runs well.

So now, you also have my vote to close this issue.